# How to play media files in JavaFX if the file name contains non alphabetic character ?

Tags: javafx

If we pass the name of any media file in JavaFX in this process:

```
    String MEDIA_URL = "C:\\Users\\Dragon-i\\Desktop\\cole\\12.mp4";
    MEDIA_URL = "file:///" + (MEDIA_URL).replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20");

    Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    final MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
    player.play();
```

Then the player plays well.
But if the file contains any character like “[” or “]” or something else like this, then the player doesn’t work.
What should be done to fix all kind of problems like this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `URI` class to parse local media file path instead of string manipulation:

```
private File file = new File("your local media file path");
private final String MEDIA_URL = file.toURI().toString();
```

then pass `MEDIA_URL` in `Media` constructor.

```
Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
```

It is not my tested code. But it should be working regardless other issues.